# Speeding up nginx requests on https with http2

Tags: nginx, ssl, http2

I'm moving my site fully over to SSL, and so far I've moved the mobile version 
over. The problem I'm having, is that its quite a bit slower on the request:

Before:
[image]

After:

[image]

The initial HTML page for example (31.html), went from taking 5ms, to a whopping 303ms :/

I'm assuming this is something to do with the fact we are now on SSL.

My SSL is set up pretty simply in my domains config file with:

```
ssl         on;
ssl_certificate      /home/chambres/conf/web/ssl.chambresdhotes.org.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /home/chambres/conf/web/ssl.chambresdhotes.org.key;
```

Are there any other tricks I can use, to help speed this up? We are rolling this out on the mobile version first to get a feel of how it will affect speed - I'm just concerned if we move this over to the desktop version as well (much heavier), it will make the speeds so much slower.

Thanks!

Comment: 5ms to load a page is very low, almost LAN level latency. To get that on the internet there may be caching going on somewhere. To get 5ms page load your client would have to be close to your server, with a fast server. 300ms is however fairly slow, but that's probably because of SSL session establishment. Once that session is set up multiplexed connections over http2 should somewhat make up for that. A connection view would be interesting to verify it's doing it properly.

Comment: Gave a detailed answer here on this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36672261/how-to-reduce-ssl-time-of-website/36678211

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2 big wins..

The first with nginx cache ssl

```
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:20m;
ssl_session_timeout 180m;
```

Also if you are really serious about speed offload your css/js/images to a CDN that supports SSL

Comment: a good site for nginx ssl is https://www.bjornjohansen.no/optimizing-https-nginx